# PHP mirror a webpage

Tags: php, https, mirror

I am trying to create a mirror of a weather widget which I use for a website. Presently, it is used on an HTTPS page, but widget server does not support that (and IE throws a tantrum with dialogs because the widget is not HTTPS)

To solve this, I would like to do is mirror the page in HTTPS to silence the security warnings. I would normally use `file_get_contents()` for this, however the page contains images which makes it a little more complicated.

**Also as a side note, there isn't any ads on my website or theirs, so there is no revenue stealing

Comment: Configure a webserver as a proxy for that site only, which will save you a lot of headaches. (If you don't know how, best ask at ServerFault.com).

Comment: At mininum you'd need to run the captured HTML through DOM and re-write ALL the urls in the html to point at your proxy script. However, remember that CSS and javascript can contain URLs as well, so you'd need to parse/rewrite everything that could be in that page - if it's got flash content, then you're really screwed.

Answer (score 2):

Use CURL to grab a page's content (images and all). You can put this in a file, then use that URL in place of where you'd use the widget's URL:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: I have just tried this, and it seems to only have grabbed the pages hmtl source (not the images)

Comment: I guess, then, your question was not clear. The HTML source is the means by which you display the images - display the HTML.  This concept is not a "mirror", but rather a proxy.